# how can i linked css stylesheet to react classes

Tags: css, reactjs

how can I attach css stylesheet to this component class divs in 
  this wrapper div

```
class Home extends Component {

          render() {
            return (

                <div class='wrapper'>
                                <NavMenu />
                                <HomeHeader />
                                <TopMain />
                                <HomeMain />
                                <Footer />
                      </div>
                );
              }
              }

              export default Home;
```

this is style sheet 
for example

```
.NavMenu {
…
…
…

}
```

is it true ?

or this for example  ==>>

```
    <NavMenu className='navmenu'/>
    <HomeHeader className='HomeHeader'>
....
```

Comment: you named your class `wrapper` so inside `.css` file it should also be called `.wrapper`

Comment: Please edit your question to identify the documentation/tutorials/examples you have used to familiarise yourself with CSS, and why these did not help. Thanks.

Comment: yes didn't use this kind of css style component

Answer (score 1):

You must create a css file, for example `App.css` and in your component you have to include this file. I always create a classname for every class.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
...
render(){
return(
    <div>
      <NavMenu className="classA"/>
      <HomeHeader className="classB"/>
      <TopMain className="classC"/>
      <HomeMain className="classA"/>
      <Footer className="classB"/>
    </div>
);
}
}
```

And it's done!
It must work!

Comment: You also can see [the styled components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics). I think this is very important and maybe resolve your question.